# Functional programming in JS

Tags: javascript, functional-programming

Playing with FP in JS.
Suppose I have 2 functions

```
getLine :: () -> IO String
cat :: String -> Task Error String
```

What is the proper way of composing this two functions?

**UPD**:
I can't see any other solution except

```
const main = () => compose(map(cat), getLine).performIO().fork(logError, printResult)
```

but I'm not sure that this is proper way of doing it.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please visit the [help] to see what and how to ask. I think people want to have more explanation of expected result as per [mcve]

Comment: You need to make an attempt at this first and if you encounter problems, you can post a question clearly explaining what you have tried and what error(s) you are getting. But it is also equally important that you do some basic research before posting your question.

Comment: I can't see any other solution except `const main = () => compose(map(cat), getLine).performIO().fork(logError, printResult)`, but I'm not sure that this is proper way of doing it.

Comment: What library are you using?

Comment: ramda + my own monads

Comment: I updated my answer. It now doesn't use `unsafePerformIO`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that you're familiar with Haskell since you're using Haskell idioms. You have the following functions:

```hs
getLine :: () -> IO String -- why isn't this simply `getLine :: IO String`?
cat :: String -> Task Error String
```

The first thing you want to do is get rid of the superfluous function wrapping the IO action:

```hs
getLine () :: IO String
```

Then, you can use [`fmap`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:fmap) to compose `cat` and `getLine ()`:

```hs
fmap cat getLine () :: IO (Task Error String)
```

Finally, assuming `Task` is analogous to [`Either`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#t:Either) and `fork` is analogous to [`either`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:either) we can do:

```hs
fmap cat getLine () >>= fork logError printResult :: IO String
```

This can be written in JavaScript as follows:

```js
getLine()
    .map(cat)
    .bind(fork(logError, printResult));
```

Now, all you need to do is implement the appropriate `map` and `bind` methods for IO actions in JavaScript.

---

**Edit:** To compose them you could simply do the following in Haskell:

```hs
(>>= fork logError printResult) . fmap cat . getLine :: () -> IO String
```

In JavaScript this would translate to:

```js
compose( bind(fork(logError, printResult))
       , fmap(cat)
       , getLine
       );
```

This assumes that `fmap` and `bind` are defined as follows:

```js
function fmap(f) {
    return function (x) {
        return x.map(f);
    };
}

function bind(f) {
    return function (x) {
        return x.bind(f);
    };
}
```

Hence, you still need to implement the `map` and `bind` methods for IO actions.

Comment: I got the same solution (see UPD), but pointfree. Isn't unsafePerformIO considered a very bad practice?

Comment: Isn't that what your `performIO` function is actually doing? It's performing IO actions in an unsafe manner. An alternative is to lift the `fork` operation into the IO monad. You can do that using the monadic bind operator (i.e. [`>>=`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:-62--62--61-)).

Comment: `Task` is actually something like Control.Monad.Task in Haskell, but with error handling. Something like https://www.npmjs.com/package/data.task
So, as I understand, I need to implement something like `either`, but for `fork` method.

Comment: No need to. The types align so even if `Task` is not like `Either` it shouldn't make a difference. All you really need to do is implement `map` and `bind`.